# Is it possible to securly remove a variable and its contents out of memory in PHP?

Tags: php, security, memory, memset

I am looking for a way to remove a variable and its contents out of ram securly within PHP. I know its possible in C/C++ and of course in underlying assembler. In C/C++/Asm so long as you don't copy the variable and stick with references to it, it remains in one place in most scenarios - how about PHP?

c/c++

```
memset(&data, 0, sizeof(PrivateData));
```

assembler

```
000000013F3072C8  mov         r8d,70h  
000000013F3072CE  xor         edx,edx  
000000013F3072D0  lea         rcx,[data]  
000000013F3072D4  call        memset (013F301352h)
```

Is there a memset in php or something equivalent?

*Edit: after thinking about it and finding PHP's memset (FFI::memset), I am now worried that the interpreter may have copies of the variable elsewhere in its internals unbeknownst to me (as I am not sure how PHP works with variables)*

Comment: No, there isn't. PHP is an interpreter and it stores variables in a way that you cannot really access, and even if you could, it could change over time. A logical question to ask is: Why would you want to do this? Perhaps if you answer that we might come up with a suggestion.

Comment: I have no idea how this is implemented, or if it is "100% secure", but it does exist: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sodium-memzero.php

Comment: I want to do this as I am creating public and private keys using PHP's OpenSSL library to create public/private key pairs. I am sure the internals of OpenSSL are doing what I intend, however once it passes the keys to PHP, I'd like to clear them once I do what I need to do - generally good practice in C/C++ - but - the languages here are not in my use case.

Comment: @ChrisHaas: OK, I'll take back my previous comment. Looks like there is something to do this with, but you really have to be careful handling your variables, to make sure another copy isn't left untouched.

Comment: Well. normally PHP is used to serve content on the web. Web clients don't have, or shouldn't have, access to the memory used by PHP on the server. This is quite a different situation in which C/C++ is mostly used, where the machine of the user _is_ the machine having the memory.

Comment: If you go down this path, you might also want to follow this RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/redact_parameters_in_back_traces

Comment: Thanks Chris I will look into that.

Comment: Down the road I plan on using an HSM, this is (hopefully) a temporary situation.